# Can Project Tango Device 3D Map an Entire Building.

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, direct3d, java-3d, google-project-tango

I would like to know if It is possible to make a 3D model of an entire building on my college campus. If I am able to make the 3D model of each room, and then somehow combine all the rooms to make a full 3D building it would be a great project for my senior internship. Please direct me to the correct information. Or please give me instructions on how to use the Project Tango Device to create a full 3D building. Ultimately, I want to use the Project Tango Device to conduct indoor mapping using  augmented reality.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Sure,  manetsus 1. I would like to know if I buy a Project Tango Developer Kit, can I make a 3D model of an entire building on my college campus. From my understanding the Project Tango device works well at room scale, but I want to know if it's possible to combine, and overlay multiple classrooms, hallways, staircases. To create a fill 3D building. How would that work? Or would I have to learn how use the Java API, or Unity SDK...

Answer (score 1):

Project Tango can export your scanned meshes to .obj files. Programs like 3DSMax allows you to import several .obj-files.

To create a mesh of a room with project tango and export the files you can use the constructor app.